# How did you find it? vs What did you make of it? vs How did it [you] go?

Tags: american-english, speech

What is the difference between those follow up questions?

For example, if my friend said "I tried making octopus dumplings for the first time last night",
can I add response follow up questions with all these 3 sentences?

Comment: "How did you find it?"  It was missing, you looked for it, and then you found it.  How did you do that?  I would not say "How did you find it?" when asking about octopus dumplings.  That sounds like an attempted translation from another language.

Comment: @GEdgar - I’d use “How did you find it?” to ask how you liked the food.  I.e:  “I found it to be very tasty but the tentacles were a little tough.”

Comment: @Jim When asking opinions, what is the difference among those 3 sentences?

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to find out.  If I wanted to know how he found the dish- I’d ask how he found it.  If I wanted to know what he made of it (to make of something is idiomatic for how one understands or rationalizes something that might be puzzling at first)  and if I wanted to know about the process of making it went I’d ask how it went.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your kind explanation. It makes sense!

Comment: @Jim Could you please give me an example in which I should use "What did you make of it"?

Comment: A: I went to see the new modern art exhibition yesterday.  B: Oh? I heard it was pretty *avante garde*. What did you make of it?   A: Yeah, it just looked like the guy spilled some paint on some newspaper and then framed it.  I didn’t get it.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your patience!
In your art exhibition example above, can't I use "How did you find it" to ask opinions about the event?

Comment: Sure, you could also say that.  It’s more neutral in its implications.